# Apache ErrorDocument for error 500 not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, apache2, web-hosting

I know this might be a duplicate, but I have better details.
I have the `.htaccess` file set to display a custom error page for the most common errors:

```
  # remove .php
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
    #Add custom error pages
    ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404
    ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403
    ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500
```

When I purposely trigger an error 500 it just gives me the default Apache page for that and also says: `Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`
I can access the error page by typing `localhost/errors/500` so it's not a problem with the permissions. I searched many forums but haven't found a solution.

**Edit:** The error 500 was triggered from a malformed request by the rewrite engine. If you type `example.com/index/` it tried to go to `/index/.php` and that caused error 500.

Comment: How do you "purposely trigger an error 500"?

Comment: www.mydomain.com/index/ generates an error because of the rewrite engine

Comment: I triggered one in PHP. I accidentally deleted a `catch` block and left the `try`. Voila nice testing material. Trouble is I can get 404 working fine but not 500 - which seems pretty common.

Answer (score 2):

A 500 Internal Server Error is a very general error. It indicates that the server encountered a *serious* error and is simply unable to process the request as normal.

Many of these 500 errors simply cannot be caught with a custom error document defined "late" in `.htaccess`.

You stand a better chance if the `ErrorDocument` is defined in the server config. But even that will not be soon enough for some errors.

However, having said that...

> ...and also says: `Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.` I can access the error page by typing localhost/errors/500 so its not with the permissions.
>
> Edit: The error 500 was triggered from a malformed request by the rewrite engine. If you type `example.com/index/` it tried to go to `/index/.php` and that caused error 500

It does appear to be *trying* to serve a custom (500) error document, but this is also encountering a 500 error.

Specifically, requesting `/index/` results in a rewrite loop, ie. `/index/.php` to `/index/.php.php` to `/index/.php.php.php` etc. It's when the server reaches the limit for internal redirects (default 10) does it trigger a 500 error.

Yes, I see this as well for *rewrite loops*. Even though the error does not appear to interfere with the serving of the ErrorDocument; the message seems to suggest that it does. Requesting the error document directly is OK.

I wonder (purely hypothetical)... since the "internal redirects" limit has been reached in this request (because of the rewrite loop), the ErrorDocument (that is also served by an internal redirect) can't be served because this limit has already been reached!? So this then triggers a 500 error for the same reason! Strictly speaking, the ErrorDocument is served via an *internal subrequest* (not an *internal redirect*), although the [Apache documentation for the `LimitInternalRecursion` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitinternalrecursion) seems to group "internal redirects" and "subrequests" together.

I can't just think of another way of triggering a 500 error, other than triggering it in code (as below - which works OK). Any (fatal) *parse errors* in the code trigger a 500 error on *every* request.

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ - [R=500]
```

The above should serve your custom 500 ErrorDocument as normal, the ErrorDocument itself is OK.

Comment: I defined it first in .htaccess. Still doesn't work.

Comment: When I say "_late_ in `.htaccess`" I mean that `.htaccess` itself is processed too late, regardless of where you actually put the directive in `.htaccess`. The main server config is processed _before_ `.htaccess` (in fact, it is processed when the server first starts up)

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you are saying now about the additional message with regards to serving the ErrorDocument. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Can you explain the line you posted. What should I put in foo?

Comment: That is just a way to trigger (ie. test) your custom 500 ErrorDocument. If you request `/foo` (this does not need to exist) then you should see your custom 500 ErrorDocument.

Comment: What do I have to do to get the 500 error page to be displayed if someone types /index/

Comment: I don't think you can, unfortunately (as per my "hypothetical" explanation above). However, typing that URL should never trigger a 500 error - you need to fix your code. An end-user should never see a 500 error under normal usage. You need to fix your mod_rewrite directives so that `/index/` does not trigger a rewrite loop (this is a different problem).